# remove categories from product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is is possible to remove all the categories from a product in WooCommerce?

I have written a script which is run every time when a product is added/updated via WP-All-Import, but there are some wrong categories on the products, which I want to clean, deleting all the categories or products is not an option, so I want clear the categories on the products and let my script decide which categories to add to this product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, actually it is very simple:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
foreach($terms as $term){
    wp_remove_object_terms($product_id, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
}
```

This code get all the therms with the 'product_cat' taxonomy, with a foreach loop I remove all the items.

Comment: where do you put this code?

Comment: @domenicocamasta I have written an plugin which runs every time when an product is added via WP All Import, there have I added this code before the new categories are processed.

Answer (score 0):

You could wipe all terms from a product using the `wp_set_post_terms` function. Setting the `append` argument to `false` ensures that all terms are overwritten.

For example:

```
wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, array(), 'product_cat', false );
```

More information on the `wp_set_post_terms` function:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/